# this and protoype javascript

Tags: javascript

Why does  alert(d.prototype) return a undefined? Shouldn't the prototyope be animaL?

```
function Dog(){

}
function Animal(){
    this.name = "name";
}
Dog.prototype = new Animal();
var d = new Dog();

alert(d.constructor);
alert(d.prototype);
alert(d.name);
```

Answer (score 3):

The `prototype` property is a property of a constructor function. It's not a property of objects created with that constructor function.

Internally any object must know what its prototype is, but it's not exposed as a property with a name.

In some implementations it may be given a weird name. In Firefox it's called `__proto__`, but obviously you can't rely on that working in any other browser.

http://www.packtpub.com/article/using-prototype-property-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

d is a instance, to get the prototype use:

```
d.constructor.prototype;
```

Comment: If the prototype on the constructor has changed since the instance was created, then that won't tell you what the object's current prototype is. It will just tell you what any future objects created with the same constructor will take as their prototypes.

Comment: when prototypal inheritance is applied right, instances should have  prototypes. in fact, instances should be `classes` as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think the drawing in http://mckoss.com/jscript/object.htm describes it (I can never remember this myself). There's a property `__proto__` in Firefox that references the prototype, but other than that, going from an instance to prototype isn't done (except checking with `instanceof`).

[image: Prototype drawing]

Image is borrowed from above mentioned URL.

Answer (score 0):

FF and chrome can give you the parent object in `__proto__` which can be accessed using `d.__proto__`

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't use `Dog.prototype = new Animal();`
Try: `Dog.prototype = Animal;` instead.

Comment: Maybe you should try it first.

Comment: There is not a single example on that page of a function object being assigned as the prototype. Why try to answer someone's question with a random guess?